# SQL table doesn't appear on page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some problems with displaying my table on a html page. Here's the code:

```
$resultaten = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM GastenBoek ORDER BY ID DESC");
$resultaten->execute();
while($rij = $resultaten->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $ID = $row['ID']; //Hier zeg ik : haal ID uit Row.
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    $Bericht  = $row['Bericht'];
    $Tijd = $row['Tijd'];
    $Datum = $row['Datum'];
    echo $Email;
}
```

I've tried using PDOStatement but that didn't solve it at all.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific, what exactly happens? What isn't happening? Does it produce any errors?

Comment: No. Its just blank. And my table is not appearing on my webpage.

Comment: Well, are you looking for errors? Is there no output what so ever? A blank page can mean that there are syntax errors. Is the connection good?

Comment: Connection is good. Connected successfully. Also no. I'm trying to make a guestbook.

Comment: Btw, `$rij` ! = `$row`, which would throw undefined variable earnings, which tells me you didn't actually check for errors.

Comment: Ah that fixed it! Mad kudos :). I didn't actually know that rij was supposed to be row.

Comment: I reformatted the code in the post a little bit. Anyway, If you found the problem, you could proceed to document what was wrong, for future visitors. (It is completely ok for someone to answer their own question.)

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this

```
$conn = new \PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$conn->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
$conn->exec("SET character_set_connection = utf8");
$conn->exec("SET character_set_client = utf8");
$conn->exec("SET character_set_results = utf8");

$resultaten = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM GastenBoek ORDER BY ID DESC");
$resultaten->execute();
$result = $resultaten->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $value)
{
    $ID = $value['ID']; //Hier zeg ik : haal ID uit Row.
    $Email = $value['Email'];
    $Bericht  = $value['Bericht'];
    $Tijd = $value['Tijd'];
    $Datum = $value['Datum'];
    echo $Email;
}
```

Comment: Why should anyone "try this"? A good answer gives an explanation what was changed and why. The issue was a typo, so the structure used in the given code is valid.